# Проблема с AJAX запросом

Tags: jquery, ajax, href

Здравствуйте дорогие знатоки! Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Вот код

```
<script>
    $("a").click(function () {
        var handler = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: handler,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {

                $(".row").html(html);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Но подгрузка контента так и не происходит. А ссылка открывается как обычная. Как можно исправить? В чем проблема? помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event.preventDefault() - Отменяет выполнение события. Например, при "клике" по ссылке, переход по ней не произойдет, если внутри обработчика будет вызван этот метод.

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    /* ваш код */
});
```

Только учтите, что при таком указании селектора, у вас клик по всем ссылкам на странице не будет срабатывать.

Comment: Вот что получилось но проблема остается той же подгрузка не происходит!А просто обычный переход!

<script>
$("a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var handler = $(this).attr('href');
  $.ajax({
  url:handler,
  cache: false,
  success:function(html){
    
    $(".row").html(html);
  }
  });
});

</script>

Comment: Не вижу, чтоб ваш код был обернут в конструкцию DOM-ready:

    $(document).ready(function(){
        /* тут весь jQuery-код*/
    });

Comment: Спасибо все прекрасно работает!

Comment: Можно еще вместо `e.preventDefault()` добавить в конец функции `click` возврат: `return false`;

Comment: *return false* проверянный способ,мне лично нравиться ))